# When sending a POST request to an external server, Node is giving me a "self signed certificate in certificate chain" error

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, axios

I'm using axios to send a POST request to an external server with some data.  Here's my axios setup, without any extras to handle the self-signed cert:

```
const https = require('https')
const axiosConfig = {
  method: 'post',
  data: callbackXML,
  url: process.env.CALLBACK_URL,
  headers: responseHeaders
}

await axios.request(axiosConfig).then((response) => {
  console.log('resp is', response)
})
  .catch(e => {
    console.log(`${helpers.getLoggingTimestamp()} error is`)
    console.log(e.toJSON())
  })
```

I know there is a solution to use locally, because I am using it already, which is

```
NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED='0'
```

However, for obvious reasons, that's not something that's acceptable in a production environment.

I've tried just about everything involving the topic here on SO, Googling, etc.  I've tried adding certs to `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS` via env variables, as well as setting the `ca:` option in an `https Agent` and passing that into an axios config.  I've also tried adding the certs via the command line, like so: `export NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=/c/code/server.crt`.

**My real question is, where is my offending cert located?  If I'm not adding the offending self signed cert, then I will never solve this.**

Side note: this is a node problem, not an axios problem, as I've tried out other request libraries and I get the same error.

Comment: a little more info, which may be helpful: I am on a Mac

Comment: more info...I was able to get around this also by a custom agent into my axios config like so: `httpsAgent: new https.Agent({
        rejectUnauthorized: false
      })` but that is less than ideal also

Comment: Is it the full CA chain? This article recommends checking to make sure you are using full CA chain by requesting to website you are trying to connect to with OpenSSL `openssl s_client -connect ${REMHOST}:${REMPORT}`

https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-resolve-certificate-errors-in-nodejs-app-involving-ssl-calls-781ce48daded